# Convert 360 degree images into mesh

Tags: modeling, image

I created several microstructures and took electron microscope pictures at a 45 degree tilt at all 360 degrees around the structure. I want to convert these images into a single 3d model of the structure but both ReMake and VisualFSM can't seem to do it (I think the contrast is too low). Is there a way to manually (or automatically) create a 3d model from these pictures??

Comment: You can process all the images to increase the contrast.  There's many tools for that.  But there's not really a texture to fix on... Also perhaps: I'm guessing the Field Of View is very small, and may be having a hard time fixing virtual camera positions (because they are very far away relatively) and reconstructing.  but may be wrong.  How accurate does it need to be?  So you have 360 images rotated precisely?  Depending how the images are, (perhaps put them in a google drive/dropbox?) I may be able to advise further.  There may be a better forum to ask too.  Cool problem.

Comment: Not a very simple task, it can be done with Agisoft, but he model may be incomplete in the bottom part because of the angle of the microscope.

Comment: I've got an image of every degree up to 211 degrees and after that I made an image every 2 degrees (because of time constrains) until I returned to the original orientation. I could make higher resolution pictures (that would show quite a bit of texture) but that would probably cost me several hours of work (these pictures cost me 3 hours already). I would like the top part to be as accurate as possible and I don't really care that much about the bottom part.

Comment: I am now running a trial version of agisoft to see if it works. it needs an hour to calculate everthing so I am going to let it run

Comment: I tried Agisoft and it was able to create a mesh but it placed all the views in a 30 degree perspective so it didn't look like anything

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Blender is not the tool. As stated in the comments there are external tools dedicated to processing the described (detailed) input into the desired output. When these tools produce a file format that Blender can read, that's how you get the data into Blender.

**This is not an endorsement of 3rd party software**

Software like Agisoft Photoscan offers a python interface to let you sidestep the ui for automation purposes - but it's out of the realm of Blender support to discuss that unless there is a concrete question about interactivity between the two programs or APIs.